# How do I obtain a HTML Label's runtime value for use in TypeScript (in Angular)?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, internationalization

I have the following label with an *i18n* (internationalization) element:

```
<label i18n="@@replacingValue">Default value</label>
```

At runtime, the "Default value" text of this label is replaced with the value given by its *i18n* element, and I need to obtain that value for usage in my TypeScript code, but how?

I've tried to pass it from the HTML to TypeScript through *@Input*, as such:

In the .HTML file:

```
<label i18n-[labelValue]="@@replacingValue" i18n="@@replacingValue">Default value</label>
```

In the .TS file:

```
@Input('labelValue') labelValue: string;
```

But the variable I tried to store it in remains "undefined". How do I get the correct value if, for example, I want to do this in TypeScript:

```
console.log(this.labelValue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to manipulate dom elements:

html file:

```
<label #myLabel i18n="@@replacingValue">Default value</label>
```

ts file:

```
@ViewChild('myLabel') el: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.el.nativeElement);
}
```

After getting the elements you can iterate the attributes and handle i18n however you want

Comment: `this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML`

Comment: originally the question was about an attribute, if he wants the inner text then you're right @Eliseo

Comment: It was indeed the innerText value that I required.